# CSS Expand document width to fit content

Tags: overflow, css

If I individually load in a div with a width of say `500px` and `display:inline-block`, when it reaches the edge of the document the next start on a new line. Is there a non JS way of making the document expand horizontally (ie. with scrollbars) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `min-width` instead of `width`
Also you might want to use `white-space:nowrap` in order to keep text in one line instead of wrapping to another line.